# Permission denied while elastic beanstalk is retrieving S3 file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

I have files stored on S3 and wrote `.ebextensions` config to automatically copy the them to new instances. I'm receiving this error in the Elastic Beanstalk console:

> [Instance: *INSTANCEID* Module: AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: null] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild] command failed with error code 1: Error occurred during build: Failed to retrieve [https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/*MyBucket*/*MyFolder*/_MyFile.txt](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/_MyBucket_/_MyFolder_/_MyFile.txt): HTTP Error 403 :  `AccessDenied`

My .ebextension config file has this section:

```
files:
    "/target/file/path" :
        mode: "000777"
        owner: ec2-user
        group: ec2-user
        source: https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/_MyBucket_/_MyFolder_/_MyFile.txt
```

In attempting to make this file copying work, I've also relaxed permissions by giving the elastic beanstalk IAM role the standard read only access policy to all of S3. It's policy is this:

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "s3:Get*",
    "s3:List*"
  ],
  "Resource": "*"
}
```

Yet the prebuild copying step still fails. Did I give the source url in the correct format? Is there another security entity/policy involved? Help please :)

Comment: I have this issue today.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution to overcome this error. It turns out adding a `Resources` section to the .ebextensions config file makes it work. The entire file becomes:

```
files:
  "/target/file/path" :
    mode: "000777"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user
    source: https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/_MyBucket_/_MyFolder_/_MyFile.txt
Resources:
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3Access:
          type: S3
          roleName: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
          buckets: _MyBucket
```

At this point, I don't know enough to grok why it has to be this way. Hopefully it can help someone who's lost move forward and eventually gain a better understanding. I based my answer on this link https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=541634

Comment: Soln above yields...Access Denied! Fail!

Comment: Worked flawlessly for me, when I ran into the exact same issue.  Thanks a bunch for posting this.

Comment: @babalu: Use "authentication: S3Access"

Comment: I agree this just doesn't work "HTTP Error 403". @MickeyCheong with `authentication` and without.

Comment: Did not work for me, this Resources-Section is not documented in the official docs (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html), probably it was a non-public feature that was removed in the meantime.

Answer (score 23):

The documentation is very sketchy on the subject (probably an ideal candidate for StackExchange Docs!).

To do this correctly with `.ebextensions`, you need to allow the Beanstalk instance IAMs user in the bucket policy, setup an `AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:` auth config and attach config to remote sources. This is kind of a hybrid of all the other answers, but all failed in one way or another for me.

Assuming your IAM instance role is `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role`:

1. Set your AWS bucket to allow the Beanstalk IAM User. Edit "bucket policy":

   ```
   {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Id": "BeanstalkS3Copy",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Sid": "",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Principal": {
                   "AWS": "<beanstalk_iam_role_arn>"
               },
               "Action": [
                   "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                   "s3:ListBucket",
                   "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                   "s3:GetObject"
               ],
               "Resource": [
                   "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>",
                   "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/*"
               ]
           }
       ]
   }
   ```

   where:

   > **beanstalk_iam_role_arn** = the fully qualified instance IAMs role. See "IAM role" associated with a running instance if available or see environment configuration. Example: `arn:aws:iam::12345689:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role`
   >
   > **bucket_name** = your bucket name
2. In your `.ebextension/myconfig.config`, add an S3 authentication block that uses your IAMs instance user:

   ```
   Resources:
   AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
     Metadata:
       AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
         S3Auth:
           type: "s3"
           buckets: ["bucket_name"]
           roleName:
             "Fn::GetOptionSetting":
               Namespace: "aws:asg:launchconfiguration"
               OptionName: "IamInstanceProfile" 
               DefaultValue: "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
   ```

   > Set **bucket_name** appropriately
3. Define a remote file and attach the S3 Authentication block:

   ```
   "/etc/myfile.txt" :
      mode: "000400"
      owner: root
      group: root
      authentication: "S3Auth" # Matches to auth block above.
      source: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/myfile.txt
   ```

   > Set your **source** URL appropriately

Comment: Looking at the [official docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-storingprivatekeys.html) it seems like the first part with the bucket policy is missing. this was the step missing for me, resulting in a 403 upon `eb deploy`

Comment: Is there any way to pass bucket name as parameter? for example, pass bucket name as environment variable in Elastic Beanstalk and then access value of that variable in this script?

Comment: I don't understand NO 3.
but after createing `myconfig.config` file i got this error
processing file (Skipping): `'.ebextensions/myconfig.config' - Contains invalid key: 'AWSEBAutoScalingGroup'. For information about valid keys, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html
ERROR   "option_settings" in one of the configuration files failed validation. More details to follow.
ERROR   Invalid option specification (Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:staticfiles', OptionName: '/public'): Unknown configuration setting.
Failed to deploy application.

Answer (score 12):

Similar to chaseadamsio's answer, you can configure the role given to the EC2 instance with a policy to access S3 resources, then use the pre-installed AWS CLI utilities to move files around.

The way I approached this is to create a role dedicated to the given EB application, then attach a policy similar to:

```
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "<sid>",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::<your_bucket_path>/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

This gives your instance access, then to get the files, add a 'commands' block to your config such as:

```
commands: 
  01-get-file:
    command: aws s3 cp s3://<your_bucket_path>/your-file.txt /home/ec2-user
  02-execute-actions: 
    [unpack, run scripts, etc..]
```

Obviously you can use other AWS CLI utlities as needed. I found this solved a lot of problems I was having with S3 access and makes deployment a lot easier.

Comment: I love your aws cli method. It save a days time. Thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to setting the `.ebextensions` config would be to set a policy on the `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role` within the IAM Manager (or create a new role specifically for your elastic beanstalk environments to sandbox your autoscaled ec2 instances.

To do so, go to the IAM manager within the web console, and click on "Roles" on the left side. You should see your instance name in the list of roles, clicking on that will take you to the administration page for that particular role. Attach a new role policy to the role under "Permissions" with a policy document matching what you want your ec2 to have permissions to do (in this case, you'd give it a policy to access an s3 bucket called `_MyBucket` and you should no longer need the `Resources` section in your `.ebextensions` config.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer, as it is the cleanest way to solve this. Thanks - I never saw the Roles section in the left side panel.

Comment: i agree this does feel easier. i'm actually having problems just adding a "fullS3access" to my EB roles, still getting permission denied when trying to view the file SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125292/elastic-beanstalk-s3-permission-not-working

Answer (score 1):

If you have your IAM role for the machine configured to get access to the file you can do the following in `.ebextensions`

```
commands:
  01a_copy_file:
    command: aws s3 cp s3://bucket/path/file /destination/
```